# Invalid type for path "security.firewalls.main.form_login". Expected array, but got string

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I am getting this error in my symfony project. My security.yml file code is below.

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Emtity\User:
            algorithm: becrypt

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path:login
                check_path:login
```

You can also see my config.yml file whick look like be

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi: ~
    #translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection:
         enabled: true
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    trusted_hosts: ~
    session:
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }
```

Please check above code i don't know which thing are missing in my code so please help me if anyone have got any solution.

I want to try login process in symfony using the security.yml file.

Comment: `check_path:login`, shouldn't it be `check_path:/login_check` ?

Comment: I have changed like your suggestion but problem is still remaining.

Comment: Your error message is `Expected array, but got string`, add a space in `login_path:login` and `check_path:login` : `login_path: login` and `check_path: login` maybe? .yml format is sensitive to this kind of problem

Comment: @goto symfony version is 3.4.6.

Comment: @MickaelLeger Thanks for your help. My problem is solved if you will add this comment in answer then i can true that answer.

Comment: Glad to hear it ! I add my anwser :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is `Invalid type for path “security.firewalls.main.form_login”. Expected array, but got string`

If you look at in your `security.yml` file, you got this :

```
form_login:
    login_path:login
    check_path:login
```

You should add a space to respect the .yml format :

```
form_login:
    login_path: login
    check_path: login
```

Hope it helps !