# Invalid type for path “security.firewalls.main.form_login”. Expected array, but got string

Tags: php, symfony, security

I am getting an error in my security.yml file, I checked this article [Invalid type for path "security.firewalls.main.form_login". Expected array, but got string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360493/invalid-type-for-path-security-firewalls-main-form-login-expected-array-but) and all the suggestion didn't help. Anyone who faced this problem before?

I tried a suggestion on this article([Invalid type for path "security.firewalls.main.form_login". Expected array, but got string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360493/invalid-type-for-path-security-firewalls-main-form-login-expected-array-but)) and they didn't work

```
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
         my_provider:
         entity:
         class: App\Entity\User
         property: username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true

            form_login: 
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
            provider: my_provider



    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

I want to create a new controller for login

Comment: You must increment the 3 lines after `form_login` so that those lines go under it

Comment: @gogaz it's only the two line after `form_login`. And providers si'nt formatted as well.

Comment: You're right, my bad

Answer (score 3):

It's not working because your `security.yml` file isn't formatted properly.
Here is a corrected version of your file :

```
providers:
    my_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: username

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: true
        provider: my_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login

access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```